# Proving a solution based off of two other solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems

I'm not sure what to do for this problem, especially with the max part and how to factor in h(t).

If f(t) and g(t) are two solutions of y'(t) = F(y(t),t), then prove that h(t) = max(f(t), g(t)) is also a solution.

Comment: See the related Q: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133773/two-distinct-solutions-of-xt-fxt-cannot-intersect-at-any-point?rq=1