# Show that differential equation has no solution that

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the IVP
$$u′(t) = f(t, u(t)), t ∈ \Bbb R$$
$$u(t_0) = u_0$$

For every choice of $t_0$ and $u_0$ there is an unique solution,

For $t_0=0$ and $u_0 =1$ the function has the solution

$$u : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$$
$$t → 1$$

Now I have to show that there is no such solution with

$$(∃t_1 ∈ \Bbb R : ˜u(t_1) > 1) ∧ (∃t_2 ∈ \Bbb R : ˜u(t_2) < 1)$$

Do I need the Lipschitz condition to show this or is there any easier way?

Comment: You just need the fact that for every value of $t_0,u_0$ there is a unique solution, and that the solution $t \to 1$ is what works for $t_0=0,u_0=1$. Suppose there is a solution $\widetilde{u}$ satisfying the conditions, for a contradiction. Use this to create two solutions of some initial value problem and contradict the uniqueness condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im new to this topic and im a bit confused since i have no specific function given here and on my lecture there are always examples with functions so I am not really sure how to apply the condition here. I assumed that you can show this with contradiction but not really sure how to apply in into the uniqueness condition.

Comment: Ah well, I understand. I'll look for a good duplicate first.

Comment: alright thanks for taking your time to help

Comment: Hi hihi haha, the basic idea is captured in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133773/two-distinct-solutions-of-xt-fxt-cannot-intersect-at-any-point). Basically, suppose that $\widetilde{u}$ existed. Then $\widetilde{u}$ is continuous, therefore there exists $t \in (t_1,t_2)$ such that $\widetilde{u}(t) = 1$. This means that the curves of the solutions $\widetilde{u}(t)$ and the solution $t \to 1$ intersect at $1$. Then you can use that post to get the contradiction.

Comment: Thanks sir, helped me alot to get the idea now

Comment: Hey , good to know I could be of help.

Comment: I have another question . If t0 = −1 and u0 = −2 how do I show that the solution is an upper bound? Is there any other post that can help here or can you give me a hint :D , since I can just find stuff with actual functions and not with only the initial conditions given.

Comment: Not sure about that one @hihi haha, I suggest that you ask a separate question about it.